# My sidebar does not seem to work. Could someone point me to the fundamental mistake I am making here?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, navigation

To anyone looking to see it in codepen: [My Codepen](https://codepen.io/brxtn/project/editor/XWRPzL)

Hamburger is defined as such:

```
  <div id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()"">
    <a>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

There is quite a bit of CSS and a little Javascript animating the hamburger, but I will leave that out.

The actual side menu itself is something like this (including script):

```
<nav id="MySideNav">
      <ul class="menumenu">
        <li><a class="menu" href="#><li>List 1</li></a>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">List 2</li></a>
    </nav>


<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("site").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("site").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
```

With CSS like this (leaving out some formatting):

```
nav{
  display:block;
  list-style-type:none;
   position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
 position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;

  nav:open{
    left:0;
  }
  nav.*:first-child{
    position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  clear: both;
  }
}
```

I've been trying to follow tutorials for a good three days but everywhere seems to have a slightly different way of going about it and I just don't know what to do. Nothing I try seems to work. I just want the menu to slide out and push the rest of the site with it and leave a transparent white film over the rest of the site.

Comment: `"mySidenav" !== "MySideNav"` your `getElementById` is using a *different* ID than the one you have on your element

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: 1. Your css definitions are nested, which is not valid. 2. Missing closing `</ul>` tag in html

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you! Although that didn't fix the problem, it evidently would have created another one so thank you!

Comment: @SebastianSimon Whoa! Such a great tool! Thank you!

Comment: @Morpheus Whoops! Sorry, that was a mistake I made copying in the code and editing out irrelevant bits!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML has many validation errors. Just check it with a simple HTML-Validator online tool, eg. this: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Just some of the errors:

1. In the first menu item there is one opening `<li>` in front of "List 1", remove it.
   `<li><a class="menu" href="#><li>List 1</li></a>`
2. You've forgot to close the `<ul>` at the end of your list items
3. Check all ID's and class names if they are correctly written, everything is case sensitive so you are not allowed to mix eg. "MySideNav" and "mySidenav"

If you always have an eye on the validity of your markup, you shouldn't run into these problems.

I hope this helps you a bit.